# Running Bpfdoor Implant

Tags: ebpf, bpf

After compiling the BPFdoor implant using

1. gcc bpfdoor.c -o bpfdoor
2. **sudo** ./bpfdoor

Does it mean that in order to run the exploit, we need root access? If so, why do we still need the backdoor if we already obtained root access?

Sorry, if I could be understanding this wrongly!

Comment: This question isn't necessarily about programming. It may be better suited for another site.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR.** Yes, you need admin. privileges to run bpfdoor. It's **not an exploit but a backdoor**; it won't exploit any privilege-escalation vulnerability.

---

As far as I understand, bpfdoor is only a backdoor in that it allows attackers to retain privileged access to a system while evading software firewalls. It doesn't exploit any vulnerability to do so, but programs the kernel with eBPF. That requires admin. privileges.

You therefore need to already have admin. privileges on the system to run bpfdoor, or you need another tool to exploit a vulnerability and gain privileges.